# How can this type of response handled in android?

Tags: java, android

I am getting the response like this from Api. In which locationSector is fixed key but the inside key may exist or not and corresponding the key value as well.
this is json string. 
How can I store this in hashmap also the inner value can also be stored in hash map like.
`HashMap<String, HashMap<String,List<String>>>`

```
  "locationSector": {
    "Adampur": [
      "Adampur",
      "Agroha",
      "Anaj Mandi",
      "Auto Market",
      "Bhadu Colony",
      "Chulibagrian"
    ],
    "Allahabad": [
      "Allahabad"
    ],
    "Gurgaon":[
      "Dlf 1",
      "Dlf 2"
      ]
  }
```

Comment: What library you are using for api calls ?

Answer (score 0):

try this out if you're using org.json library:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
Map<String, Object> response = new ObjectMapper().readValue(str, HashMap.class);
```

str = youre json String.

Simple as this, if you want a studentId,

```
String studentIds = response.get("student id").toString();
```